# PHP , sqlsrv connection not working

Tags: php, sql-server, search

hi am trying to connect to sql server through php, search and display the  results based on search string. following is the index.php

am successful in getting the results separately by writing query but not through this search form

Following is the search.php

```
  <?php

$button = $_GET ['submit'];
$search = $_GET ['search']; 

if(!$button)
echo "you didn't submit a keyword";
else
{
if(strlen($search)<=1)
echo "Search term too short";
else{
echo "You searched for <b>$search</b> <hr size='1'></br>";

}
$serverName = "xxxx";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"xxxx", "UID"=>"xxxx", "PWD"=>"xxxx");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo );

$Query = "SELECT employee_name FROM employees WHERE employee_name like '%".$search."%'";
$run = sqlsrv_query($conn,$Query);


$foundnum = sqlsrv_num_rows($run);

if ($foundnum==0)
echo "Sorry, there are no matching result for <b>$search</b>.</br></br>1.";
else
{
echo "$foundnum results found !<p>";

while($row = SQLSRV_FETCH_ARRAY($run,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    echo $row['Employee_name'];
    }
sqlsrv_free_stmt($run);
}
}
?>
```

Comment: What type of error do you get?

Comment: am not getting any error, but am not getting any results as well

Comment: You have `$run = sqlsrv_query($conn,$Query);` but you never check if it returns false, therefore you can't determine if you have errors. The fact you're not getting anything back indicates there is an error which you haven't handled. 


TL;DR: handle the error.

Comment: See [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-connect.php) with example on checking for errors in connection object. It could be any number of issues: server name, remote settings, user grants, ...

Comment: I was able to run and get the results using the same connection but query was select top 10 employee_name from employees.     I used ths to check if connection was working fine or not

Comment: hello all, i used  $params = array( $search );
$options =  array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET );
$run = sqlsrv_query($conn,$Query,$params, $options); and its working fine , but am getting all the records as a paragraph. i want in one by one order

Answer (score 0):

use

This for mysqli connection

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
```

This for mysql connection

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
```